# How to put an image in an invert rectangle with css and php

Tags: php, css

I have been asked to put every single image I upload into a field and make it look like this. 
[image]
Every time i upload an image, i have to add that image to the red space under the space available.

**Question**

Is there a way of displaying an image in a field like on the image with css and php ?

Comment: Use css `transform: rotate(angle);`

Comment: No problem but i do not want to rotate the picture but the triangle and the picture must be inside the triangle just as it is on the image above. How to do that ? For example Bootstrap has the ability of making an image round, i need something similar but with the rotated triangle . How to achieve that ? Tks

Comment: but it's not triangles, rotate the whole container, reverse the rotation of the images so they end up back to vertically oriented. Use border radius to round the corners